# Try Throw Catch in Java

Tags: java, try-catch

I'm working on a Sudoku solver in Java as a fun introduction to the language. One of the things I'm having my code do is check if the puzzle is solvable before it tries to solve it. I thought it would be a good idea to use `try{}` `catch{}` for this but I cannot get the code to compile.

```
public class SudokuSolver2
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 9x9 integer array with currentPuzzle

        // check current puzzle and make sure it is a legal puzzle, else throw "illegal puzzle" error
        try
        {
            // 1) check each row and make sure there is only 1 number per row
            // 2) check each column and make sure there is only 1 number per column
            // 3) check each square and make sure there is only 1 number per square

            throw new illegalPuzzle("");
        }
        catch ( illegalPuzzle(String e) )
        {
            System.out.println("Illegal puzzle.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}

public class illegalPuzzle extends Exception
{
    public illegalPuzzle(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Couple of questions...

1. Why won't the code compile in its current form?
2. Is there a way to write the code so that I do not have to use a "String message" parameter? All the examples I looked at use a string parameter but I don't really want it or need it.
3. Is there a way to write the code so that I do not have to create my own custom exception class? In other words, can I just throw a general error? All the examples I looked at created their own custom exception but I don't need that level of detail.

Thanks!

Comment: Classes should be named with first letter in uppercase, so IllegalPuzzle instead illegalPuzzle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer 1. The code won't compile in its current form, cause your catch clause should be written as follows:

```
catch (illegalPuzzle e)
{
  System.out.println("Illegal puzzle.");
  System.exit(1);
}
```

Answer 2. Just throw `Exception` (the base class of all Exceptions) in your try, and remove `illegalPuzzle` class altogether. Here's how:

```
public class SudokuSolver
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try
    {
      // other statements
      throw new Exception();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println("Illegal puzzle.");
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer 3. Answer 2 answers this part as well.

Answer (score 1):

Following figure show you the flow of a try catch block

[image]

try with,

```
try{
      throw new Exception("IllegalPuzzleException");
}catch (Exception e){
     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to throw specific exception for the Illegal Puzzle Exception and catch other Exceptions in the other code block which might be thrown by other part of the code.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
       throw new IllegalPuzzle("Illegal Puzzle");
    } catch ( IllegalPuzzle e ) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Inside Exception: " + ex.getMessage() );
    }
}
```

Also please look at below link before writing the throw code: [Throwing exceptions in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528417/throwing-exceptions-in-java)